# How to add navigation path in A-Frame?

Tags: three.js, aframe

I tried various ways A-Frame but, I can't able to get a good way to make a path so that avatar can't go outside that and also can't pass through walls and objects which are there in the scene. I tried to make my own navmesh using blender but maybe I'm missing something.

**So please help me regarding this in A-Frame !!**

```
 <a-scene
      inspector-plugin-recast
      renderer="antialias: true;
    colorManagement: true;
    sortObjects: true;
    physicallyCorrectLights: true;
    highRefreshRate: true;"
    >
      <a-assets>
        
        <a-asset-item id="rig" src="./navmesh.gltf"></a-asset-item>
      </a-assets>
      

      <a-entity
        id="rig"
        movement-controls="speed:0.15; constrainToNavMesh: true"
        position="0 0 5"
      >
        <a-entity
          camera
          position="0 1.6 0"
          look-controls="pointerLockEnabled: true"
        >
          <a-cursor nav-pointer raycaster="objects: [nav-mesh]"></a-cursor>
        </a-entity>
      </a-entity>
      <a-entity gltf-model="#rig" nav-mesh visible="false"></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
```

navmesh.gltf is to give the navigation path to the camera so that is could not go outside this mesh. This gltf i've generated by using

> aframe-inspector-plugin-recast.js.

So, it's working but when I'm making my own navmesh and adding it then, either browser didn't load the scene or my camera always goes outside it.

Comment: Please add more details. What code have you tried already?

Comment: I tried navmesh.

Comment: Please add your source code. It was hard to even understand that you were creating a game. "Navigation Path" usually refers to `<nav>`, like Navigation bars in HTML

Comment: Ok I'll try to add

Answer (score 1):

This is a good tutorial on the concept of navmesh:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y52czIft9OU

Other non simpler ways to create a system similar to navmesh is by using physics systems like Ammo.js which is used widely for game development in AR/VR.
You would basically create walls around your arena so that the avatar does not go beyond it. You can set the [ammo-body](https://github.com/n5ro/aframe-physics-system/blob/master/AmmoDriver.md#ammo-body) for the walls to static and the avatar to dynamic.
While the collision logic would need a [collider](https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/tree/master/components/aabb-collider/), there are many different ones you can research and test out what works for you the best.

Comment: It's quite interesting and I love the way of physics which you are explaining. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 1):

The question asker really does need a nav mesh. However, for those looking for an answer to the headline question (how to make something move along a predetermined path), see this repo, and the included `follow-path` component:
https://github.com/kylebakerio/aframe-curve-component